# Why is my html website loads so slow and freezes after switching to an another program/s?

Tags: html, css, performance, bootstrap-4, freeze

I'm making 3 website, two of them works really well, but the last one for some reason loads very slowly, if I wait a bit it loads and works well, but if I alt+tab to something else the whole site just freezes. What could be the problem?

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url(wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fading {
  background-image: url('fatyol.png');
  width: 880px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#cim {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#nav {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.kep {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
  -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
}

.hajokep {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
  -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
}

.fejlec {
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.labjegyzet {
  background-color: rgba(29, 120, 180, 0.712);
  margin-top: auto;
  color: azure;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.bal {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.jobb {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: white;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: white;
}

p {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.extendpage2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 90px;
}

table {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
  -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(8, 1, 1, 0.452);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="kirandulas.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Kirándulás</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <p id="cim" class="navbar-brand">Kirándulás</p>
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Összefoglaló</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <p class="nav-link active">Első nap</p>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="site2.html">Második nap</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="fading">
    <header class="fejlec">
      <h1>Első nap</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md">
        <img src="SiofokViztorony.jpg" alt="Víztorony" class="hajokep">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="szallas.jpg" alt="Szállás" class="hajokep">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Késő reggel, 9:30 körül indultunk el a vonatállomásról, nekivágva egy 2 és fél órás egy helyben utazásnak Siófokra.</p>
    <p>A vonatról leszállva negyed órás séta mellett keresztül vágtunk Siófok Fő terén, melynek közepén egy hatalmas víztorony áll, amely 2022 őszén lett felújítva. Jelenleg kilátóként és kávézóként üzemel a érdeklődők számára.
      <br>A torony mellett még számos más bolt is található a Fő téren.</p>
    <p>Ezeken keresztül vágva megérkeztünk a szállásra. Lepakolást követően az osztály útjának volt engedve a kora esti órákig. Voltak, akik a közeli boltokat, voltak, akik a Balatont látogatták meg, de voltak azok is, akik a szálláson foglalták el magukat.</p><br>
    <img src="sutogetes.jpg" alt="Sütögetés" class="kep">
    <p>Ahogy az este lassan beköszöntött, úgy az esti tevékenység is kezdetét vette: tűzön sütögetés!
      <br>Megraktuk a tüzet és előkészítettük a húsokat, zöldségeket, italokat.
    </p>
    <p>Késő este, mikor már mindenki elfogyasztotta, amit elkészített magának, újra szabad elfoglaltság vette kezdetét egészen addig, amíg utolsók is közülünk le nem feküdtek.</p>
    <div class="extendpage2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="labjegyzet">
    <div class='bal'>
      <p>Elérhetőségeink: email<br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;email<br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;email</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobb">
      <h1><a href="email">name</a></h1>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I basically looked over the whole code, but I couldn't find anything which could cause it.

Comment: Well, have you looked at your browser's performance profiling tools?

Comment: have a look at the dev tools network tab in e.g. chrome and reload your page. Sounds like sth is loading way to long. Also give that script tag for the bootstrap js a go without the `integrity` attribute. Maybe thats what's taking so long.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the images take up too much space, so you should compress them.

Also you can reduce the images' dymension if the size is not needed to be displayed under a certain pixel size. That is, you could display a smaller image under a smaller screen-size.

60 to 70 percent of image quality is enough, without loosing the image overall display quality, in terms of compression.
For example, a fullsize image is 2 to 5 Mb large, with a resolution of 4032x3024 pixel. You don't need it that large. If you compress it with an image editor like Gimp or Photoshop, you can get a filesize like 658kb or smaller, and so you can gain a lot of space, thus the download time will be much less.